# How to design a versioning table inside SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, database

I will preface this right off the bat by saying that I am new to database design.

I have been working to rewrite some legacy code that controls an import process into one of our pieces of software. Part of this new process includes the modification of the incoming XML files (that come into our system via FTP) to remove certain elements as well as swap values in special cases.

As a part of the new system, we are implementing a way of versioning inside the database so that we can pull the most recent version of the xml directly from that instead modifying the file over and over again. In order to prove that this can be done, I have created a very simple table inside of SQL Server 2016 that stores the XML, then wrote a simple PowerShell script to pull that XML file from the database and store it inside of an object. Now that I know that this is indeed possible, I need to refine how I design the table.

This is where my expertise starts to take a hit. As of right now, the table contains three columns: `xml_Version`, `xml_FileID`, and `xml_FileContents`.

The general idea is to have a GUID (`xml_FileID`) that is tied to each version of the XML and another column that indicates what version of the XML that is. I would also assume that you need some way of tying each version of the XML to it's original file, too.

I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction about how I should go about designing the table to accomplish this task. I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I think what I'm having the most trouble grasping is what I should be referencing when I'm trying to grab data out of the database. Storing the XML in the table with a unique identifier is the easy part - but the unfortunate part is that there's nothing in the XML itself that I can grab out of there that would be able to uniquely identify the correlating data within the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just curious - How big is the XML file you're storing with each version and how often does it change? You may want to take those factors into account regarding whether you want to keep the entire XML in the DB or just links to the files or even just deltas between the versions... Also, although you didn't ask, have you looked at versioning products like git? Just helps to point you  towards the best solution for your case....

Comment: The XML files can be rather large (they're from a 3rd party vendor so they contain a lot of information we don't use) - they can vary from 500 lines to upwards of 50,000. Even though we're trimming a lot of that data off, we still want to be able to go back and reference the original XML if we need to. Also, we do use git - but that wouldn't really work in this situation. The idea is that the import script will pull the most recent version of the XML directly from the database instead of relying on a file path like it currently does.

Comment: Have a column on the table that is the same for every version of a given document. And another column on the table that indicates status (basically 'current version', 'archived version', and maybe 'root version'). That way you can easily get the most recent version of the document by just using the document identifier and the status of 'current'. A third column with a version number would be useful for pulling archived versions. I wouldn't bury this information in the XML blob itself. Give this info its own column for efficiency.